# Failing WiX build due to condition

Tags: wix, windows-installer

My build is failing due to the following condition:

> ..wxs(138) : error LGHT0204 : ICE03: Bad conditional string; Table:
>   Condition, Column: Condition, Key(s):

```
<Feature .....>
   <MergeRef Id="Feature" Primary="yes"/>
   <Condition Level="0">((PROP1="prop1") OR (PROP2="prop2") OR (PROP3="prop3") OR (PROP4="prop4" AND OR PROP5=""))</Condition>
</Feature>
```

Is there any mistake in the condition?
Is there any other way to specify this condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never seen `AND OR` used in conditions before. Removing `OR` makes it compile. Hard to tell what you are trying to achieve here without more information.

Comment: No problem. Something useful done today :-). Glad it worked.

Comment: That is such a short answer for you, Stein!  I'd expect to see a description of how WiX  compiles, links and then validates the MSI,  a reference to ICEs and CUBs,  a description of what ICE03 tests for and a breakdown of conditional statement syntax. ;)

Comment: Seeking that elusive developer economy-of-expression ;-).